# How to set display property inline with !important

Tags: javascript, css, styles, inline

I want to write an **inline style** viz `block !important` using javascript code. Code looks like this

```
element.style.display = 'block !important'; // This does not work (Approach 1)
```

However,

```
element.style = 'display:block !important'; // works perfectly (Approach 2)
```

But **Approach 2 is not acceptable for the obvious reason it will over-ride earlier inline styles**. You can see this in this **[DEMO at Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IMiKahUD/2/edit?html,css,js,output)**

Q1: How can I set `display: block !important` property using javascript and it has to be inline.

**Q2: I want to know why Approach1 does not work ?**

Comment: Here´s another good solution:
element.setAttribute ('style', 'display: block !important;');

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it will help you:

```
element.style.cssText += ';display:block !important;'
```